# In JNI, How to access JSONObject's values in java from C++, put some values in it and return?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

```
Using org.json.JSONObject;
```

Current code

Java Code:

```
class sample  
{  
    int val = 7;  
    String str = "Hai";  
    public native void callCpp(JSONObject jo);  
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {  
        sample s = new sample();  
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();  
        jo.put("val",val);  
        jo.put("str",str);
        s.callCpp(jo);  
    }  
}
```

CPP Code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sample_callCpp(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject jobj)  
{  
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("org/json/JSONObject");  
    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getInt", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I");    

    jint val = env->CallIntMethod(arg, method, env->NewStringUTF("val"));  
    std::cout << "val: " << val << std::endl;    

    jmethodId method2 = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getString", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");  
    jstring strVal = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(arg, method2, env->NewStringUTF("strVal"));  
    const jchar *ptr = env->GetStringUTFChars(strVal, nullptr);  
    std::string strVal_copy(ptr);    

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strVal, ptr);  
    std::cout << "strVal: " << strVal_copy << std::endl;  
}
```

From this I can retrieve "`val`" and "`str`" and use in `CPP`.

But my problem is, I cannnot do the exact oppposite of this.

I need to send values to "val" and "str" to that JSONObject.

The following seems to be wrong, Help me correct it!

JAVA CODE:

```
void valFromCPP(JSONObject jo)  
{  
    System.out.println("Val is ::  " + jo.getInt("val"));  
    System.out.println("Str is ::  " + jo.getString("str"));  
}
```

CPP CODE:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sample_disp(JNIEnv *env, jobject cobj, jobject jsonjobj)  
{  
   jclass jsoncls = env->FindClass("org/json/JSONObject");  
   jclass ccls = env->GetObjectClass(cobj);  

   jobject newObj;  
   jmethodID constructorID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls,"<init>","()V");  
   newObj = env->NewObject(jsoncls, constructorID);  
   jmethodID putStringID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls, "put", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/json/JSONObject;");  
   if(putStringID == NULL)  
   {  
       printf("\n putStringID not created!\n");  
       return;
   }  
   jmethodID putIntID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls, "put", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/json/JSONObject;");  

   jmethodID valFromCPPId = env->GetMethodID(ccls, "valFromCPP", "(Lorg/json/JSONObject;)V");  
   newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putStringID, env->NewStringUTF("str"), env->NewStringUTF("Hai"));  

   newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putIntID, env->NewStringUTF("val"), 7);  
   env->CallVoidMethod(cobj, valFromCPPId, newObj);
}
```

Im getting the error :

```
putStringID Not Created  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: put
```

Even though i made sure there is put method, and it returns "this", which is that object.

Comment: Your C++ code invokes undefined behavior.  It is supposed to return a `jobject`, but nowhere do you return anything.

Comment: Actually tried doing that.. instead of calling method, to return the jobject. I'll edit it now

Comment: No, it isn't a matter of "trying".  You *must* return a value from a C++ function that is declared to return a value.  If you don't return a value, the behavior becomes undefined.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying.. I had that return statement when I tried returning the object, I changed the "returning" part to method calling and I forgot to update here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ive updated the question, can you please go through this and tell me??, i cannot access the "put" method from JSONObject even though it is there.

Comment: [According to this](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html), the return type for `put` is `JSONObject`, not just `Ljava/lang/Object/`.

Comment: Yes, so what to do?

Comment: Your method signature is wrong.  It should be something like `(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/json/JSONobject;`

Comment: I've changed that, the problem still is not resolved

Comment: Did you change the signature for `putStringID` as well? Update your question.

Comment: Yes I did. Actually the problem occurs when i try to send Objects as Parameters

Comment: Update the code in your question. I still see references to `java/lang/Object` which should be `org/json/JSONObject`.

Comment: The signature for `putStringId` is still wrong. It should be `(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/json/JSONObject;` to match with `JSONObject put(String, Object)`.

Comment: Yeah, Forgot to change that!! @Botje

Comment: So what does and does not work now?

Comment: putStringID always returns null,, hence always throws Exception

Comment: That cannot be. Where did you get this implementation of `org.json.JSONObject`?

Comment: From a GitHub repository, I don't remember the name though.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Botje/48c8e9d528b812796c19c45711a03bc9 This works for me, using the 20180813 version of the org.json library. I removed your `ccls` and returned the object instead of calling a callback, but that is all I changed. (and should not matter)