# want to pass a ArrayList<jsonobject> from cpp to java using jni

Tags: java-native-interface

actually i am new to jni and i wanted to know how to pass ArrayList" jsonObject " from cpp to java .i did not have an idea how to do it .Can some one help me writing the code.the jar used for this is json-simple 2.2.
this is my code tried only jsonobject to write

```
#include<jni.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<C:\Users\yuvaraj-pt3134\Desktop\User\User.h>
using namespace std;
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_User_jo(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls,jobject obj)
{
    jclass jsoncls = env->FindClass("org/json/JSONObject");
    jobject newObj;
    jmethodID constructorID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls,"<init>","()V");
    newObj = env->NewObject(jsoncls, constructorID);
    jmethodID putStringID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls, "put", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/json/JSONObject;");
    if(putStringID == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n putStringID not created!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    jmethodID putIntID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls, "put", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/json/JSONObject;");

    newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putStringID, env->NewStringUTF("str"), env->NewStringUTF("Hai"));

    newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putIntID, env->NewStringUTF("val"), 7);
    static jclass java_util_ArrayList;
  static jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_;
  jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_add;
  java_util_ArrayList      = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
  java_util_ArrayList_     = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "<init>", "(I)V");
  java_util_ArrayList_add  = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
  jobject result=env->NewObject(java_util_ArrayList,java_util_ArrayList_,10);
  result=env->CallObjectMethod(result, java_util_ArrayList_add, newObj);
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726102/in-jni-how-to-access-jsonobjects-values-in-java-from-c-put-some-values-in-i This question seems to tackle the very similar topic.

Comment: actually i tried it and couldnot get an solution rather than method not found error

Comment: What implementation of JSON are you using: This class, `org/json/simple/JsonObject`, where is it coming from?

Comment: json simple 2.2 jar file

Comment: i edited my question actually i got data inserted into json object but i could not insert that json object into arraylist

Comment: it returns null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList#add` returns a `boolean`. You need to use `CallBooleanMethod` instead.
Don't forget to return `newObj` (your list) instead of `result` (the result of the `add` call)!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<jni.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<C:\Users\yuvaraj-pt3134\Desktop\User\User.h>
using namespace std;
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_User_jo(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls,jobject obj)
{
    jclass jsoncls = env->FindClass("org/json/JSONObject");
    jobject newObj;
    jmethodID constructorID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls,"<init>","()V");
    newObj = env->NewObject(jsoncls, constructorID);
    jmethodID putStringID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls, "put", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/json/JSONObject;");
    if(putStringID == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n putStringID not created!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    jmethodID putIntID = env->GetMethodID(jsoncls, "put", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/json/JSONObject;");

    newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putStringID, env->NewStringUTF("str"), env->NewStringUTF("Hai"));

    newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putIntID, env->NewStringUTF("val"), 7);
    static jclass java_util_ArrayList;
  static jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_;
  jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_add;
  java_util_ArrayList      = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
  java_util_ArrayList_     = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "<init>", "()V");
  java_util_ArrayList_add  = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
  jobject result=env->NewObject(java_util_ArrayList,java_util_ArrayList_,10);
  env->CallBooleanMethod(result, java_util_ArrayList_add, newObj);
    newObj = env->NewObject(jsoncls, constructorID);
  newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putStringID, env->NewStringUTF("str"), env->NewStringUTF("yuvaraj"));

    newObj = env->CallObjectMethod(newObj, putIntID, env->NewStringUTF("val"), 9);
    env->CallBooleanMethod(result, java_util_ArrayList_add, newObj);
    return result;

}
```